# How to generate tkinter's element with for dict/list and save their value and update them?

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm still new to code (less than 1 year experience). I want to make a simple POS program but i can't figuring how to get the value from the loop and update the labels. I tried to learn from what i search in the internet but not able to get the result i wanted. Here is the code below.

````
item = ["A", "B", "C"]

labels = {}
lvalues = {}
buttons = {}
values = {}


fcount = 0

app = tk.Tk()

def plus(item):
    val = values[item]
    val += 1
    values[item] = val 
    print(lvalues[item])

for i in item:
    values[i] = 0
    labels[i] = tk.Label(app, text=i)
    labels[i].grid(row=fcount, column=0)
    lvalues[i] = tk.Label(app, text=values[i])
    lvalues[i].grid(row=fcount, column=1)
    buttons[i] = tk.Button(app, text="+")
    buttons[i].grid(row=fcount, column=2, command=plus(i))
    fcount += 1
    
print(labels)
print(values)

app.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Does this help? Add this between line 29 and 31. buttons[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda e,i=i:plus(i)) And remove command line 28.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to embrace the StackOverflow pinciples on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your questions for the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please don't use `command=plus(i)` in the `grid` function. write it in `tk.Button(...)`.
2. You can use `command=(lambda item=i: plus(item))`, but not `command=plus(i)`.
   If there is no parameters, you can use `command=plus`.
3. Use `xxx.config()` to update the elements.

Does this code work?

```py
import tkinter as tk

item = ["A", "B", "C"]

labels = {}
lvalues = {}
buttons = {}
values = {}


fcount = 0

app = tk.Tk()

def plus(item):
    values[item] += 1
    lvalues[item].config(text=str(values[item]))
    print(lvalues[item])

for i in item:
    values[i] = 0
    labels[i] = tk.Label(app, text=i)
    labels[i].grid(row=fcount, column=0)
    lvalues[i] = tk.Label(app, text=values[i])
    lvalues[i].grid(row=fcount, column=1)
    buttons[i] = tk.Button(app, text="+", command=(lambda item=i: plus(item)))
    buttons[i].grid(row=fcount, column=2)
    fcount += 1
    
print(labels)
print(values)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good answer. Consider using `for fcount, i in enumerate(item)` rather than incrementing fcount by 1 each time. enumerate will do this for you.

Comment: @Zxd2009 Thanks for the answer. With this code the UI was updating the value but the print value was `.!label` which is not the result i wanted. How do i able to extract the value to use for other thing like calculation?

Comment: If you mean to get the value of `lvalues[item]`, you can `print(values[item])` in line 18. That is because `values[item]` is a number but `lvalues[item]` is an element of tkinter.

Comment: Okay, it's my fault didn't see what variable i called. Thanks it worked as i expected.